# Javascript search video using youtube API through API Key

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, api-key

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Search</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="buttons">
    <label> <input id="query" type="text"/><button id="search-button" onclick="keyWordsearch()">Search</button></label>   



    <div id="container">
      <h1>Search Results</h1>
      <ul id="results"></ul>
    </div>           

    <script>
     function keyWordsearch(){
        gapi.client.setApiKey("AIzaSyCFdNzrcERfUCd1R5rk1h3JAjXNT9svi5g");
        gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
                makeRequest();
        });
          }

      function makeRequest() {
        var q = $('#query').val();
        var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
                q: q,
                part: 'snippet', 
                maxResults: 10
        });
        request.execute(function(response)  {                                                                                    
                $('#results').empty()
                var srchItems = response.result.items;                      
                $.each(srchItems, function(index, item) {
                vidTitle = item.snippet.title;  

                $('#results').append('<pre>' + vidTitle + '</pre>');                      
        })  
    })  
}
    </script> 
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady">  </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So what I am trying to do is to search videos using keyword on Youtube using Youtube API. However, the example provided on the youtube page requires "authentication" as well. I need to do it without authentication, just by using API key. What is happening right now is that when I press the search button, it does nothing. I have been trying to figure it out myself, but I do not find any other questions relating to what I am experiencing... help...

Comment: It is working for me without any issues, check this - http://prntscr.com/dfu9wn

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly working my friend. I ran your code and here's the [screenshot](https://imgur.com/SRidsvz).

So what I did was:

1. Ran my server in Python using 'python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000' //im on Linux
2. Went to browser, opened localhost and located my search.html file which contains your code
3. Voila, it works.